# Simple word diff algorithm

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, diff

I am currenlty looking for a simple and lightweight algorithm to compare two simple strings.

For example, if we take those two strings :

- "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
- "The plick brown fox tumps over the crazy dog"

It should signals me that the 2 first letters of the second word are different, etc.

For now I have a very simple algorithm that compares words :

```
/// <summary>
    /// Make a diff between two strings and returns words indices
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<int> Diff(string a, string b)
    {
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();

        string[] asplit = a.Split(' ');
        string[] bsplit = b.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < asplit.Length; i++)
        {
            if (bsplit.Length > i)
            {
                if (asplit[i].CompareTo(bsplit[i]) != 0)
                {
                    indices.Add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return indices;
    }
```

So this is going to tell me which words (using a split on space characters) are different.

I've read many topics around here about implementing complex algorithm or using an existing library.

But I am retrained by the .NET compact framework (WP7) and I don't wan't something that can compare two files or two texts, I just need a word comparison.

Is there any library or algorithm that could fit ?
Thanks :).

Comment: what if a word is inserted into the middle of one of the sentences so it skews the match?  Should it report every subsequent word different?

Comment: The standard way to solve this problem is to implement the Longest Common Subsequence algorithm. It is a pretty straightforward algorithm. I have a JScript implementation here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/21/189974.aspx  converting it to C# is left as an exercise.

Comment: @James Michael Hare : let's say I have "my little pony" and "my sweet little pony", it should only report "sweet". I think my too simple algorithm fail for this.

Comment: @eric-lippert Thanks for sharing your piece of code. I will try to figure out how it works and if it helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might take a look at the [DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/) project.

The core functionality looks like it's in \DiffPlex\Differ.cs  It even has a Silverlight viewer but it might require some porting.

**Edit:**

I wanted to add that DiffPlex specifically supports word comparison as per your question. It might have not been obvious being buried among all the other character, line, etc. comparison methods.

Comment: This seems really nice, I'll try to integrate only the core and see if it's not too much for my little requirement.
Thanks !

Comment: It works really well, thanks again.

The diff core is really light and powerful, with an easy to understand interface.

Using an additional example (UnidiffSeqFormater from http://diffplex.codeplex.com/discussions/254392), I was able to perform a complex char diff in few lines.